# Iterate addEventListener over object properties

Tags: javascript, loops, object, dom

I am trying to add an Event Listener to multiple DOM elements, so I created an object containing all of them. Now I am trying to figure out how to loop over this object so I can add the same Event Listener to all of them. I can always do this the long way, but I wanted to keep things more compact and concise. I tried to use a for..in loop, but got an error.

My code:

```
var realID;

function getFormId(){

var formID = document.querySelector("div[id^=PC]").id;
var actualID = formID.split("");
realID = actualID[0] + actualID[1] + actualID[2] + actualID[3] + actualID[4] + actualID[5];

} getFormId(realID);

var boxes = {
  titleBox: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_cboTitle"),
  firstNameBox: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtFirstName"),
  middleNameBox: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtMiddleName"),
  lastNameBox: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtLastName"),
  country: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_Country"),
  address: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_tb_AddressLine"),
  city: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_tb_CityUS"),
  state: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_StateUS"),
  zip: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_tb_ZipUS"),
  phone: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtPhone"),
  email: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtEmail"),
  cardName: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtCardholder"),
  cardNumber: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtCardNumber"),
  cardType: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_cboCardType"),
  cardExpirationOne: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_cboMonth"),
  cardExpirationTwo: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_cboYear"),
  cardSecurity: document.getElementById(realID + "_DonationCapture1_txtCSC")
}

for ( var box in boxes ){
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if ( monthlyButton.classList.contains("blue-button") || yearlyButton.classList.contains("blue-button") ){

    } else {
      monthlyButton.classList.remove("lite-grey-button");
      monthlyButton.classList.add("red-button");

      yearlyButton.classList.remove("lite-grey-button");
      yearlyButton.classList.add("red-button");
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: For..in loop the box is an index not the value. You should be using boxes[box]

Comment: @PrashanthKR very helpful, thank you!! Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the for loop to reference the value instead of the key within the boxes object..

```
for (var box in boxes) {
    boxes[box].addEventListener("click", function() {

      if (monthlyButton.classList.contains("blue-button") || earlyButton.classList.contains("blue-button") ) {

    } else {
      monthlyButton.classList.remove("lite-grey-button");
      monthlyButton.classList.add("red-button");

      yearlyButton.classList.remove("lite-grey-button");
      yearlyButton.classList.add("red-button");
    }   }, false); }
```